# Angular: How to bind an array model attribute to a copy able div element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

First of all I apologize for the bad title, I wasn't sure exactly how to describe it.

I have this div for the user to enter contact information pertaining to a "program" for which the user also entered data. Right now you can only enter 1 set of contact information in this div:

```
<div id="programContactContainer" class="container">

      <div id="programContact">
        <div class="form-group mt-2">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactName"
                 required
                 [(ngModel)]="model.contact.name" name="contactName">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-2">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactEmail"
                 required
                 [(ngModel)]="model.contact.email" name="contactEmail">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-2">
          <label>Phone</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactPhone"
                 required
                 [(ngModel)]="model.contact.phone" name="contactPhone">
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add another contact" (click)="cloneContactDiv()">
```

If you click that button it adds an identical div below the existing one so the user can enter multiple contacts.

Code for copying div:

```
  cloneContactDiv(){
    const myDiv = document.getElementById(('programContact'));
    const divClone = myDiv.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('programContactContainer').append(divClone);
  }
```

This is the model for both the program and the contact info (I know that not all of this is used in the question but I thought it might help):

```
export class ContactModel {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
}

export class ProgramModel {
  category: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  shortDescription: string;
  support: string [];
  address: string;
  location: [];
  areaServed: string;
  baseLocation: string;
  website: string;
  topic: string [];
  ownerLid: string;
  keywords: string[] = [];
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
  notification: boolean;
  daysForNotice: number;
  filter: string [];
  active: boolean;
  /// Contacts
  contact = new ContactModel();
  /// Departments
  departmentContact = new ContactModel();
}
```

If I change `contact = new ContactModel();` to `contact: ContactModel[] = [];` then I can save an array of them, but I have no idea how to handle this in the html page. As you can see, the contact info was bound like this: `[(ngModel)]="model.contact.name"`, but how do I handle that when there is more than 1 and an unknown number of how many?

I have added pics for clarity:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuVJz.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should never need a function like this in angular:

```js
  cloneContactDiv(){
    const myDiv = document.getElementById(('programContact'));
    const divClone = myDiv.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('programContactContainer').append(divClone);
  }
```

In fact, you should never need to use the document object at all.

Just put your models in an array and use the `*ngFor` directive to repeat them in the html. Let's call the array `models` in your component.ts. Then in your component.html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let model of models" class="container">
<div id="programContact">
        <div class="form-group mt-2">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"
                 required
                 [(ngModel)]="model.name">
        </div>
<div class="form-group mt-2">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"
                 required
                 [(ngModel)]="model.email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-2">
          <label>Phone</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"
                 required
                 [(ngModel)]="model.phone">
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add another contact" (click)="addContact()">
</div>
```

Angular will loop through the array and repeat the `programContactContainer` div for each model. You can access all properties of the model within the div. If you add another element to the array, the html will be updated automatically.

Since you never need to use `getElementById()` you generally don't need to add id's either.

**To be more clear**

```js
models: ContactModel[] = [{name: "", email: "", phone: ""}];

addContact() {
  this.models.push({name: "", email: "", phone: ""})
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand how this is any different than what I have already minus the copying the div. How can I add multiple different contacts if I only have 1 div with text boxes for the data?

Comment: The `*ngFor` statement? Like I said, it duplicates the div for each element in an array. I think you should read the docs, this is one of the basic angular directives.

Comment: I realize that, but even if I put all my models in an array (2, because I have 2 models) that would only give me an array of length 2 and will only allow me to enter 2 contacts. I am either not understanding your answer or I wasn't clear enough in my question.

Comment: I don't know how many elemetns will be in the array. There will be X contacts depending on how many the user wants to input and that decision is made after the page loads...

Comment: Just do exactly what you're already doing, but instead of cloning the div, just add an object to an array. Each new object should contain all the information for each new contact. Just use `push` to add a new entry. The html will update itself.

Comment: Mate, the functionality and look will be exactly the same, I'm afraid I can't explain it any clearer. I think you just need to do the angular walkthrough.

Comment: Ok, I might be able to help you. ````Just put your models in an array and use the *ngFor directive to repeat them in the html.```` elaborate on this. What 'models' are you referring to? The only 2 'models' I can think of are the ProgramModel and the ContactModel. It doesn't make sense to put the ProgramModel in an array as there is only ever 1 of them. So what exactly did you mean by this?

Comment: Whatever information you need to capture in your forms, since you'll attach each property using `[(ngModel)]`. I'm assuming that's your contact model....

Comment: I added some code to the answer maybe that'll help you understand.

Comment: Yes that does make it more clear, that's exactly what I did. The confusion came from when you said to put the models in an array. No models are being added to an array, rather I am adding objects to an array of the type of the model. Check my answer to clarify that. But either way yes thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. This may or may not be what @Chris Hamilton was trying to explain, but this is what I did:

Changed `contact = new ContactModel();` to `contact: ContactModel[] = [];`.

Then in the html page:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of model.contact" id="programContactContainer" class="container">

      <div id="programContact">
        <div class="form-group mt-2">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactName"
                 required
                 [(ngModel)]="item.name" name="contactName">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-2">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactEmail"
                 required
                 [(ngModel)]="item.email" name="contactEmail">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-2">
          <label>Phone</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactPhone"
                 required
                 [(ngModel)]="item.phone" name="contactPhone">
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr/>
      </div>
    </div>
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add another contact" (click)="cloneContactDiv()">
```

And the funciton:

```
  cloneContactDiv(){
    this.model.contact.push(new ContactModel());
  }
```